# Events-- 'mouseup' not firing after mousemove

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to drag an image with Javascript (no libraries). I am able to listen to `mousedown` and `mousemove` events. For some reason, I am not able to capture the `mouseup` event after `mousemove`. (I can capture `mouseup` if it is a click but not if it is a drag).
I have tried to listen to the event on document, window, and the image. 
Here's the url to my test page:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/move.html?w=74a0d498

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 88):

Found the issue, if it is going to be of help to anyone:

I added `event.preventDefault();` in the `mousedown` event and now I am getting `mouseup` notifications.

Comment: This definitely reduced the chance of the mouseup not firing but it will still occasionally not fire if I'm moving the mouse very fast, it seems. Very strange.

Comment: Please don't follow this blindly! `preventDefault()` will stop event bubbling from happening (https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#event-processing). Now, if you'd add the code, then I'll try to figure out the particular problem in your case.

Comment: An explanation of why this works would be very helpful. Just providing code to copy and paste may not be a good solution for everyone. In my case, calling event.preventDefault() breaks other functionality. It would be nice to know why preventDefault() is needed so I can work through my specific use case.

Comment: you have ended my two hours effort. browser thought that I'm dragging and the mouseup event was not firing.

Answer (score 15):

Strangely, I've found that when I set my text as unselectable using the below CSS, that inhibits the `mouseup` event from firing as well -- perhaps this will help someone else.

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the `mouseup` event not fire on my target `div` because its parent `div` began consuming drag events. I clicked my target `div` and this caused my `mousedown` and `mousemove` handlers to run. I was expecting to see a `mouseup` but I did not.

In my case, I had a parent `div` living beneath my target `div` in the same location where I launched my mouse button click, and instead of bubbling up the `mouseup` event on my document once I let go of the left mouse button, I instead got a `dragend` event fire on its parent `div`.

The solution for me was simply to set `user-select: none;` CSS property on the parent `div` which houses my target `div` and to make sure I set `user-select: text` on my target `div`. This property seems to disable dragging for my parent `div` and because it has stopped consuming drag events, my `mouseup` event now properly bubbles its way up.

I presume the reason why this might happen is because the browser starts thinking your mouse move is actually part of a drag event on another element, at which point it seems to stop reporting the standard mouse events and switches to drag events instead.

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining what's happening. My solution was to add a `dragend` listener to the target `div` since messing with the CSS didn't help, but your answer is the only one here with sufficient detail that it was actually helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this exact same issue!  Adding `event.preventDefault();` worked for me but I was forced to add it to both the mousedown and mousemove functions.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above answers reliably worked to ensure a mouseup event.

Here's what I discovered works consistently:

```
document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    console.log("html mouseup");
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initEvent("mouseup", true, true);
    document.getElementById('drag-me').dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

If mouseup fires on target element, it does not fire on html, and if it did not fire on target, it will fire on html.

Answer (score 1):

For above two methods:

- add `e.preventDefault()` in `mouseup` event
- add `user-select: none` CSS rule

Tried on Chrome 87 but both useless. Finally I add a additional `mouseout` event listener and it fired when drag out of element.

Answer (score 0):

The event which you want to fire in mouseup , You can fire in mousedown and inside the function write `event.stopPropagation()`.

It will stop the drag event.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be of help to anyone:

I recommended you use `window` instead of `document` when adding Event `mouseup`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in selection. Some elements are draggable, when user - having unknowingly uncollapsed selection (likely across many non-text elements), starts moving his mouse with mouse button pushed down he drags these elements alongside the movement of his mouse.

Try setting `draggable="false"` on html elements where `mousedown` event starts or if it doesn't work try clearing or collapsing selection on `mousedown`.
Clear:

```
getSelection().setPosition(null);
```

A bit cleaner, collapse:

```
const selection = getSelection();
selection.setPosition(selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset)
```

Setting `draggable="false"` worked for me when working with `mousedown` event starting with an `<img>` element and clearing selection worked when I had selections spanning over multiple elements on a control panel an this made some `input[type="range"]` elements unusable (click event worked but not thumbnail dragging).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when using React and the following things helped me:

1: Change the purpose of the event from

```
document.addEventListener
```

to

```
window.addEventListener
```

As suggested by user [Vo Hieu Nghia Phan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13869797/vo-hieu-nghia-phan). As a result, the `useEffect` hook looks like this:

```
React.useEffect(
    () => {
        window.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
        window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
            window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
        };
    },
    [mouseDown, mouseUp]
);
```

I don't know why, but when using `document.addEventListener`, if the change of `mouseUp` is frequent, then the `'mouseup'` event doesn't work. If the change of `mouseUp` is not frequent (it won't occur after the mouse down and before the mouse up), this problem doesn't occur.

2: I think it can help also those who do not use React. In the `"mouseDown"` event handler I call:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

It is not necessary to call `e.stopPropagation();`.
However, you should be careful when using this method because `e.preventDefault();` may change the expected behavior of your application after a mouse down. As a way to mitigate the effects, you can call `e.preventDefault();` not always, but by condition, for example, when clicking on a certain element or an element with a certain selector.