# jQuery Mouse Events not allowing to move

Tags: jquery, mouseup

I'm creating a simple script that adjusts the panel sizes (horizontally) by grabbing (mousedown) the divider in between the panels. (I have a snippet to test below)

It works great the first time, but it has a bug.

Whenever i Grab the "#divider" by holding down left mouse button and adjust horizontally, release left-mouse button it works. But if the second step is to:

(A) Immediately grab the "#divider" again and repeat => Nothing Happens. It wants me to click on the screen to move the panel.

(B) Click anywhere on the screen THEN grab the "#divider" and drag => It works fine.

What do I need to fix so that the user can grab the divider and adjust without having to click the screen first?

```js
$(function() {
 
   //Store the container object in cache
   let $container = $("#container");
 
    //When the user holds the mouse down on the divider, identify the x-coordinate and store in the container. Also note that we are trying to adjust the panel ("data-inmove" = "1")
 $(document).on("mousedown", "#divider", function(e) {
  $container.attr({"data-start":e.pageX, "data-inmove":"1"});
 });
 
    //When the mouse has been released, check to see if we have an "inmove" variable equal to "1".
    // if so, then change the panel width. Finally reset the variables
 $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
  if ($container.attr("data-inmove") == "1") {   
   $("#leftPanel").css("flex", "0 0 " + (e.pageX-3) + "px");
  }
  $container.attr({"data-start":"0", "data-end":"0", "data-inmove":"0"});
 });
 
});
```

```css
#container .col {
  padding-left:0px !important;
  padding-right:0px !important;
}

#container {
  width:95%;
  margin:10px auto;
  border:1px solid #929292;
  min-height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

#leftPanel {
  flex:0 0 200px;
  background-color:grey;
}

#divider {
  flex:0 0 3px;
  background-color:#333;
  cursor:e-resize;
}

#rightPanel {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<strong>Grab the black bar in between the panels. Adjust it horizontally. If you try it a second time (without clicking anywhere else), it won't work. It will wait until you click the page instead. Why does it do this?</strong><br/>

<div class="row" id="container" data-start="0" data-end="0" data-inmove="0">
    <div class="col" id="leftPanel">
      
    </div>
    
   <div class="col" id="divider"></div>
    <div class="col" id="rightPanel">
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish. This creates separate `mousedown`/`mouseup` events which set a `down` variable to true or false. This is tested on a nested `mousemove` instead, replacing the `if($container.attr("data-inmove") == "1"){...}` with `if(down){...}`.

This is the new script:

```
  // Creates a boolean if mouse is down
  var down = false;
  // Use mouse events to change it
  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    down = true;
  }).mouseup(function() {
    down = false;  
  }); 

  $(document).on("mousedown", "#divider", function(e) {
    $container.attr({"data-start":e.pageX, "data-inmove":"1"});
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      //check if down or not before changing properties
      if(down){
        $("#leftPanel").css("flex", "0 0 " + (e.pageX-3) + "px");
        $container.attr({"data-start":"0", "data-end":"0", "data-inmove":"0"});      
      }
    })
  });
```

And here is the full working code:

```js
$(function() {

  let $container = $("#container");

  // Creates a boolean if mouse is down
  var down = false;
  // Use mouse events to change it
  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    down = true;
  }).mouseup(function() {
    down = false;  
  });  

  $(document).on("mousedown", "#divider", function(e) {
    $container.attr({"data-start":e.pageX, "data-inmove":"1"});
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){

      //check if down or not before changing properties
      if(down){
        $("#leftPanel").css("flex", "0 0 " + (e.pageX-3) + "px");
        $container.attr({"data-start":"0", "data-end":"0", "data-inmove":"0"});      
      }
    })
  });

});
```

```css
#container .col {
  padding-left:0px !important;
  padding-right:0px !important;
}

#container {
  width:95%;
  margin:10px auto;
  border:1px solid #929292;
  min-height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

#leftPanel {
  flex:0 0 200px;
  background-color:grey;
}

#divider {
  flex:0 0 3px;
  background-color:#333;
  cursor:e-resize;
}

#rightPanel {
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<strong>Grab the black bar in between the panels. Adjust it horizontally. If you try it a second time (without clicking anywhere else), it won't work. It will wait until you click the page instead. Why does it do this?</strong><br/>

<div class="row" id="container" data-start="0" data-end="0" data-inmove="0">
  <div class="col" id="leftPanel">

  </div>

 <div class="col" id="divider"></div>
  <div class="col" id="rightPanel">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you didn't do an `e.preventDefault()` in the `mousedown` handler. See this answer:

[javascript-events-- 'mouseup' not firing after mousemove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506041/javascript-events-mouseup-not-firing-after-mousemove)

Confirmed working with your code just by adding that one line, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NathanHawks/jrgo2ect/12/).

PS: Kudos to @chris for proposing an alternative solution with better UX, but I too wanted to know why this wasn't working.